# Why is the result of the problem at position 1 of a list instead of 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

Okay so, I've started learning Python, started doing last year's Advent of Code puzzles and on the Day 2 puzzle, my result stores itself at the position 1 of a list instead of position 0 as the puzzle says it should. The number I get is correct, but not at the right position for some reason.
Anyone with an idea as to why this is happening?

Code: Python 3

```
f = open("input2.txt")
opcode = f.read().strip('\n').split(',')
opcode = [int(i) for i in opcode] 

opcode[1] = 12
opcode[2] = 2

for i in range(0, len(opcode), 4):
    opcodes = opcode[i]
    inputA = opcode[opcode[i+1]]
    inputB = opcode[opcode[i+2]]
    output = opcode[opcode[i+3]]

    if opcodes == 1:
        opcode[output] = inputA + inputB
    elif opcodes == 2:
        opcode[output] = inputA * inputB
    elif opcodes == 99:  
        break  
    else:
        print("Uknown opcode")

print(opcode)
```

Day 2 Puzzle: https://adventofcode.com/2019/day/2

Input2 text file numbers:

```
1,0,0,3,1,1,2,3,1,3,4,3,1,5,0,3,2,1,9,19,1,19,5,23,1,13,23,27,1,27,6,31,2,31,6,35,2,6,35,39,1,39,5,43,1,13,43,47,1,6,47,51,2,13,51,55,1,10,55,59,1,59,5,63,1,10,63,67,1,67,5,71,1,71,10,75,1,9,75,79,2,13,79,83,1,9,83,87,2,87,13,91,1,10,91,95,1,95,9,99,1,13,99,103,2,103,13,107,1,107,10,111,2,10,111,115,1,115,9,119,2,119,6,123,1,5,123,127,1,5,127,131,1,10,131,135,1,135,6,139,1,10,139,143,1,143,6,147,2,147,13,151,1,5,151,155,1,155,5,159,1,159,2,163,1,163,9,0,99,2,14,0,0
```

Result:

```py
[1, 4690667, 2, 14, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 3, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 9, 36, 1, 19,
 5, 37, 1, 13, 23, 42, 1, 27, 6, 44, 2, 31, 6, 88, 2, 6, 35, 176, 1, 39, 5,
 177, 1, 13, 43, 182, 1, 6, 47, 184, 2, 13, 51, 920, 1, 10, 55, 924, 1, 59,
 5, 925, 1, 10, 63, 929, 1, 67, 5, 930, 1, 71, 10, 934, 1, 9, 75, 937, 2, 13,
 79, 4685, 1, 9, 83, 4688, 2, 87, 13, 23440, 1, 10, 91, 23444, 1, 95, 9, 23447,
 1, 13, 99, 23452, 2, 103, 13, 117260, 1, 107, 10, 117264, 2, 10, 111, 469056,
 1, 115, 9, 469059, 2, 119, 6, 938118, 1, 5, 123, 938119, 1, 5, 127, 938120,
 1, 10, 131, 938124, 1, 135, 6, 938126, 1, 10, 139, 938130, 1, 143, 6, 938132,
 2, 147, 13, 4690660, 1, 5, 151, 4690661, 1, 155, 5, 4690662, 1, 159, 2,
 4690664, 1, 163, 9, 0, 99, 2, 14, 0, 0]
```

Expected result: 4690667 as the first number in the list, not 2nd

Comment: What's in input2.txt? What do you print out and how is this different from what you expect?

Comment: And what is the day 2 puzzle?

Comment: Edited the main post with the puzzle link and my input file

Comment: Is this python2 or python3? And you should get in the habit of closing your file handles.

Comment: @JaredSmith Python 3

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The puzzle says that the 4th opcode operand is the index at which you should store your result.
Your code uses that operand to lookup the new value at which it then stores the result.
Lets say your 4th element is = 30. You should then store your value at index 30.

Your code instead reads the 4th element (again lets say opcode[i+3]=30) and then looks
at the value of opcode[30] (lets say that value is opcode[30]=20), then saves your result at opcode[20] (at the index 20), instead of opcode[30] (at index 30).
In other words the value of the operand you read is the index at which you store the result, not a value which you need to use to find the index at which you will store the result.

Replace the line
output = opcode[opcode[i+3]]

with
output = opcode[i+3]